# How can I increment an int attribute in a EF database in MVC through JQuery, Ajax, JSON and ObjectResult?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I currently have a database model Downloads and it has the attribute "TimesDownloaded", it counts the amount of times the download link has been clicked. I have an Html ActionLink which helps me doing so using a controller. But this is very inefficient. I would like to ask basic guiding on how I could increment this DB attribute in my MVC using Ajax, JQuery, JSON and ObjectResult all together?

```
    public IActionResult Record(int downloadID)
                {
                    Download Download = _context.Downloads.Single(i => i.DownloadId == downloadID);
                    int count = Download.AantalKerenGedownload++;
                    _context.Entry(Download).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                    return Redirect(Download.Link);
}
```

View

```
@Html.ActionLink("Downloaden", "Record", "Downloads", new { downloadID = item.DownloadId}, null)
```

Comment: What makes you think _this is very inefficient_? And ajax is for staying on the same page so is not appropriate

Comment: My controller is loaded with data I needed ways to decrease controller data

Comment: Why? What you doing is correct (although you could get some minor performance using a stored procedure and make just one db call)

Comment: That's true. I will keep it like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.

Try

```
public IActionResult Record(int downloadID)
{
    Download Record = _context.Downloads.Single(i => i.DownloadId == downloadID);
    Record.AantalKerenGedownload += 1;
    _context.Entry(Record).CurrentValues.SetValues(Record);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return Redirect(Download.Link);
}
```